# Struct inside a struct call in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, tree

I got this struct and I want to call it by a good way !

```
struct TreeNode {
    int val;
    struct TreeNode *left;
    struct TreeNode *right;
};
```

I made this code for the call of my struct :

```
struct TreeNode left2 = {
            4
};
struct TreeNode right2 = {
            5
};
struct TreeNode left = {
        2,
        &left2,
        &right2         
};
struct TreeNode right = {
        3
};
struct TreeNode binary = {
    1,
    &left,
    &right

};
```

But that's a little bit loud, is there another way (without changing the struct), simplest, to do it ?

Comment: What you need is to write a function that will insert data in the tree.

Comment: You can't call a struct. You can only call functions

Comment: Yeah, you need functions for it. And I cannot really see a good implementation of it without dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put all the nodes into a single array
(I put the root node into index#0) :

---

```
struct TreeNode {
    int val;
    struct TreeNode *left;
    struct TreeNode *right;
    };

struct TreeNode all[] = {
        { 1, &all[1], &all[2]}, // Binary(root)
        { 2, &all[3], &all[4]}, // Left
        { 3, NULL, NULL},       // Right
        { 4, NULL, NULL},       // Left2
        { 5, NULL, NULL},       // Right2
        };
```